# Basic Line Integral for Work

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I've been doing some basic line integrals to find the work done along some curves, but have made a mistake somewhere.

I have the following vector equation for the force:

$$F(x,y,z)=\langle3\sqrt z,-x,4\sqrt y\rangle$$

Now, I'm supposed to integrate along the curve $C_3\cup C_4$ where $C_3$ is the line segment from the origin to $(1,1,0)$ and $C_4$ is the line segment from $(1,1,0)$ to $(1,1,1)$. Let's look at the original integral:

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_{C}[F\cdot\dot r]\;ds\\\
& =\int_{C_3}[F\cdot\dot r_3]\;ds+\int_{C_4}[F\cdot\dot r_4]\;ds\\
\end{align}$$

Clearly we have the following parametrizations for $r_3$ and $r_4$.

$$r_3=\langle t,t,0\rangle$$

$$r_4=\langle 0,0,t\rangle$$

Their gradients:

$$\nabla r_3=\langle1,1,0\rangle$$
$$\nabla r_4=\langle0,0,1\rangle$$

And a parametrized force:

$$F_3(t)=\langle3\sqrt t,-t,0\rangle $$
$$F_4(t)=\langle0,0,4\sqrt t\rangle$$

And we have the following:

$$I=\int_0^13\sqrt t-t \;dt+\int_0^1 4\sqrt t\;dt$$

$$I=\frac{17}{6}$$

I know I'm making a stupid mistake somewhere and would really appreciate some help identifying it.

Comment: You have a couple mistakes. Firstly, your $r_4$ isn't quite right (check that it has the right endpoints). Then you are plugging in your parameterization into $F$ wrong, so go back and check your $F_3$ and $F_4$. It looks like you've been trying to match up which coordinates are 0, rather than using the coordinates of $r$ as inputs for $F$. Finally and least importantly, you've got some notational errors. The integral with the circle means an integral over a closed loop, not just any line integral, and you're just taking the time derivative of $r$, not the gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\vec{F}(x,y,z) = \langle 3\sqrt{z},-x,4\sqrt{y}\rangle$ be a vector field over the domain $\mathbb{R}^3$, and let $C=C_3\cup C_4$ be a $3$-dimensional curve.

Then a parametrization of $C_3$ is 
$$
\vec{r}_1(t)=(1-t)\langle 0,0,0\rangle +t\langle 1,1,0 \rangle, \mbox{ where } 0\leq t\leq 1,
$$ 
and a parametrization of $C_4$ is 
$$
\vec{r}_2(t)=(1-t)\langle 1,1,0\rangle +t\langle 1,1,1 \rangle, \mbox{ where } 0\leq t\leq 1.
$$ 
So the parametrizations for $C_3$ and $C_4$ simplify as 
\begin{align*}
\vec{r}_1(t)&=\langle t,t,0 \rangle, \mbox{ where } 0\leq t\leq 1, \mbox{ and } \\
\vec{r}_2(t)&=\langle 1,1,t \rangle, \mbox{ where } 0\leq t\leq 1. \\
\end{align*}
So 
\begin{align*}
\int_C \vec{F}\circ d\vec{s} &= 
\int_{C_3} \vec{F}\circ d\vec{s} + \int_{C_4} \vec{F}\circ d\vec{s} \\ 
&= \int_0^1 \vec{F}(\vec{r}_1(t))\circ \vec{r}_1'(t) \, dt 
+ \int_0^1 \vec{F}(\vec{r}_2(t))\circ \vec{r}_2'(t) \, dt \\ 
&=  \int_0^1 \langle 0,-t, 4\sqrt{t}\rangle \circ \langle 1,1,0\rangle \,dt 
+ \int_0^1 \langle 3\sqrt{t},-1,4\rangle \circ \langle 0,0,1\rangle \,dt \\ 
&= \int_0^1 -t \, dt + \int_0^1 4 \, dt \\ 
&= -\dfrac{t^2}{2}\Bigg|_0^1 + 4t \Bigg|_0^1 \\ 
&= -\frac{1}{2} + 4 \\
&= \boxed{\frac{7}{2}}. \\ 
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've found a few errors in your process.

First of all, if $C_4$ is the line segment connecting $(1,1,0)$ to $(1,1,1)$, then $r_4$ should be $(1,1,t)$.

Next your force functions are off for each curve. For $F_3$, we are on the curve $C_3$ parametrized by $(t,t,0)$, hence
\begin{align}
x &= t \\
y &= t \\
z &= 0
\end{align}
That gives $F_3(t) = (0, -t,\ 4\sqrt{t})$

And correcting for the new $r_4$, we get $F_4(t) = (3\sqrt{t}, -1,\ 4)$.

Try it again with these corrections.

Also, a few notational nitpicks:

- You shouldn't use the round integral $\oint$ unless the curve your integrating around is *closed*. Instead just use the standard integral sign $\int$
- $r_3$ and $r_4$ are *single*-variable functions (of $t$), hence you aren't really taking the "gradient", you should more correctly write them as $dr_3/dt$ or simply as $\dot r_3$.